# Update Panel not working asynchronously

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a Master page where I have placed a Script Manager as under:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

In content page, I have an Update Panel with the Datalist and a Button as follows:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" onitemdatabound="DataList1_ItemDataBound" RepeatLayout="Flow">
<ItemTemplate>
 <div class="post-heading">
  <div class="pull-left image">
    <img src="http://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_1.jpg" class="img-circle avatar" alt="user profile image">
  </div>
 <div class="pull-left meta">
  <div class="title h5">
   <a href="#"><b>Ryan Haywood</b></a>
    made a post.
  </div>
  <h6 class="text-muted time">1 minute ago</h6>
 </div>
</div> 
<div class="post-description"> 
 <asp:Image ID="Image2" class="img img-responsive" ImageUrl='<%#Eval ("pimg") %>' runat="server" />
 <p><asp:Label ID="postlabel" class="postlabel" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("ptext") %>'></asp:Label></p>
 <div class="stats">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default stat-item">
   <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up icon"></i>2
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default stat-item">
   <i class="fa fa-share icon"></i>12
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="post-footer">
 <div class="input-group"> 
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment" type="text">
   <span class="input-group-addon">
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>  
   </span>
 </div>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
<asp:Button ID="Button2" class="btn-block btn-primary" runat="server" Text="Load More" onclick="Button2_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" />
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The problem is that when I click on this Load More button, data is fetched fine but full page postback is happening instead of partial postback.
Why and how it can be resolved?

Comment: I tested your code. Complete page can't refreshed! Are you sure complete page refreshed?

Comment: yeah, i kept a breakpoint on page load event and it was hit. Also, the browser table shows rotating circle that represents page loading. And I find nothing wrong in my code.

Comment: @ITSagar There is no big difference between full and partial postbacks from this point of view. Each request (full or partial) creates an instance of a page, raises all its life cycle events. But for partial postbacks only update panel's content is sent to client.
Also, try to add `UpdatePanel1.Update()` into Button2_Click

Comment: @EvgenyGorb the content in update panel is getting updated on button click so its not an issue. But it seems doubtful that all the events will be fired in partial postback. I have implemented similar code in many sites and i never saw the page loading icon rotating in the tab. It happened only in this code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your questions are always out of the box. I mean, I always see your questions with some unique issues that are hard to rectify. Why is that so??? :P
bye the way, you code looks absolutely fine. I ran into a similar issue days back and figured out that for some extra designing, I was referring to an online Javascript library. As soon as I removed the link, things started working.
I really needed those resources and tried to replace it with the css link, and it worked fine.
Give it a try, may be you are running with the same issue.

Comment: Hi. got a message hit on this question after a long time. I thought it would not be resolved. Any ways, I am referring to some CDNs like JQuery, FontAwesome, Bootstrap, etc. Let me check if your solutions works for me

Comment: Hey, removing the js script link to fontawesome worked perfect. Thanks a lot for your help. I will look for an alternative or would store it locally instead of referring online. Thanks again.